# Juntar dos resultados en una misma tabla

Tags: sql-server, sql

Estoy intentando que dos querys diferentes se agregen en una misma tabla:

```
    declare @semana nvarchar(10)
    set @semana=(select datepart(week,getdate()))

    select SUM(CANTIDAD) AS Qty1 from tbl_Entrada where dia=('Monday')  and semana=@semana --Primer resultado

    select  sum(cantidad) as Qty2 from tbl_Entrada where dia=('Tuesday')  and semana=@semana --Segundo resultado
```

De esta manerea se arrojan dos resultados por separado, sin embargo quiero que esos resultados (Qty1,Qty2) aparescan en uno solo como si fuera la misma sentencia.

Comment: Te comparto el link oficial de W3C que explica todas las funciones de SQL, incluido como dicen anteriormente, la función UNION. Link:
https://www.w3schools.com/SQL/sql_union.asp Espeor te sirva!
Saludos!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esto no es necesario calcularlo en 2 consultas diferentes, sino que es más eficiente en una sola consulta:

```
DECLARE @semana int; --el resultado es un int, no nvarchar
SELECT @semana = DATEPART(WEEK,GETDATE()); -- esta es la sintaxis correcta

SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN dia = 'Monday' THEN Cantidad END) Qty1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN dia = 'Tuesday' THEN Cantidad END) Qty2
FROM tbl_Entrada 
WHERE dia IN ('Monday','Tuesday')
AND semana = @semana;
```

Comment: Perdona mi ignorancia compañero, veo que me falta por aprender, no sabia para que servia el `IN` , me haz abierto un mundo,Saludos

Comment: @CarlosR93 lo importante es aprender, por lo que no hay nada que perdonar

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar el operador UNION

```
select SUM(CANTIDAD) AS Qty from tbl_Entrada where dia=('Monday')  and semana=@semana --Primer resultado
UNION
select  sum(cantidad) as Qty from tbl_Entrada where dia=('Tuesday')  and semana=@semana --Segundo resultado
```

Nota que debes llamar igual las columnas en las dos consultas. `UNION` por defecto toma solo valores distintos, utiliza `UNION ALL` para obtener todos.
No obstante, el escenario específico que se ilustra se puede realizar en una consulta como señala [Lamak](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/83476/24400). `UNION` sería más aplicable en casos de tener resultados de dos tablas o consultas independientes en general.

Comment: En el caso de querer dos filas como resultado, lo mejor sería usar `SELECT dia, SUM(cantidad) Qty FROM tbl_Entrada WHERE dia IN ('Monday','Tuesday') GROUP BY dia`

Comment: CarlosR93, correcto, como los ejemplos de Lamak si se puede hacer en una sola consulta el escenario en cuestión pues sí que es más eficiente.

Comment: De la dos formas he aprendido el dia de hoy, gracias compañeros.